# tikz: Drawing a graph with a thick white edges snugly connecting two big vertices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, graphs

I am struggling to draw a graph on 2 vertices where the two big vertices are connected by a white edge.  I have two issues:

1. **the gap**: the edge meets my vertices at a tangent rather than fitting snugly against/under it
2. **white edge**: white edges don't show up on white backgrounds; however, I would like the edge to appear with a clearly visible (somewhat thick) black border

My code snippet:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, fill=white, draw=black, minimum size = 1cm] (v2) at (-4,1) {};
    \node [circle, fill=white, draw=black, minimum size = 1cm] (v1) at (-7,5) {};
    \draw [line width = 1cm,draw=gray]  (v1) edge (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

is a bit of an exaggeration, but hopefully it illustrates my first issue.  This would look pretty sloppy in a paper or a talk.

I am at a loss for problem (2).  Am I wrong to use tikz edges to draw/fill edges like vertices/nodes?  What should I be using instead?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve these outcomes by drawing the connections on the `background` layer between the node centers, and by using a `double` line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \node [circle, fill=white, draw=black, minimum size = 1cm] (v2) at (-4,1) {};
    \node [circle, fill=white, draw=black, minimum size = 1cm] (v1) at (-7,5) {};
    \scoped[on background layer]{
    \draw [line width = 1cm,draw=gray]  (v1.center) -- (v2.center);}
  \end{scope}   
  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \node [circle, fill=white, draw=black, minimum size = 1cm] (v2) at (-4,1) {};
    \node [circle, fill=white, draw=black, minimum size = 1cm] (v1) at (-7,5) {};
    \scoped[on background layer]{
    \draw [double distance=6mm,thin]  (v1.center) -- (v2.center);}
  \end{scope}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. I think this is slick and perfectly solves my problem.  You're awesome.